# SilverStripe: Form works on main page but not on a child page

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following form code:

```
ContactPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    static $allowed_actions = array(
        'submit'
    );

    public function Send() {

        $contact = new Contact();
        $validator = new RequiredFields('Anrede', 'Vorname', 'Nachname', 'Email', 'Message');

        $fields = new FieldList(
            new TextField('securityidentifier', 'securityidentifier', $this->cryptTime()),
            new DropdownField('Anrede', 'Anrede:*', $contact->dbObject('Anrede')->enumValues()),
            new TextField('Vorname', 'Vorname:*'),
            new TextField('Nachname', 'Nachname:*'),
            new EmailField('Email', 'E-Mail-Adresse:*'),
            new TextareaField('Message', 'Nachricht:*')
        );

        $actions = new FieldList(
            new FormAction('submit', 'Senden')
        );

        return new Form($this, 'submit', $fields, $actions, $validator);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This works fine if I use it as a single Page. When I try to use it as child page the form does not show up. I get the headline, I get the content but I don't get the form.

Any ideas why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: What does "subpage" mean?

Comment: Is the subpage also a ContactPage?

Comment: @bummzack with subpage I meant childpage.

Comment: @wmk it is. That is what confuses me.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a restriction on allowed children somewhere? `private static $allowed_children` will allow an array of allowed children types, so maybe you can't have a ContactPage type as a child of the page you are tying to create a ContactPage under? If that's the case, the child page will default to a normal page type, the simplest way is to look in the Settings tab of the page you expect to be a Contact Page to see it's type from the dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is defined on `ContactPage_Controller`. If the child page on which you're trying to render it is not a descendant of `ContactPage`, then that method is not visible through inheritance. There are several options.

1) Put the form in `Page_Controller`. Typically, all your pages inherit from that, so they will have access to the form. Not great practice, though. Try to keep your `Page` classes lean.

2) Create an extension that injects the form factory method and handler into a controller. This is more of the "horizontal" approach rather than the vertical approach of inheritance, and tends to scale better.

3) Along the same lines, create a trait that does the same thing. Probably a better option, since extensions are idiosyncratic and will probably be deprecated at some point.